# How to call Binding function from a method?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a Slider Binded to the ScaleX of a Line, like the following code:

```
/* Graphics on Canvas */
Line lR = new Line();
lR.X1 = 0;
lR.Y1 = 0;
lR.X2 = 150;
lR.Y2 = 150;
lR.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
lR.StrokeThickness = 2;

/* declare ScaleTransformation */
ScaleTransform lRSt = new ScaleTransform();
TransformGroup lRTran = new TransformGroup();
lRTran.Children.Add(lRSt);
lR.RenderTransform = lRTran;

Binding sliderRBind1 = new Binding();
sliderRBind1.Source = sliderR;
sliderRBind1.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");
BindingOperations.SetBinding(lRSt, ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, sliderRBind1);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(lRSt, ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, sliderRBind1);


/* Slider - Slider should be placed outside the canvas to prevent being redrawn */
Slider sliderR = new Slider();
sliderR.Minimum = 1;
sliderR.Maximum = 3;
sliderR.Value = 1;
sliderR.TickPlacement = TickPlacement.BottomRight;
sliderR.TickFrequency = 0.2;
sliderR.IsSnapToTickEnabled = true;
```

Code works fine. But if I move the ScaleTransform to a method, the Binding is lost.

```
/* Graphics on Canvas */
Line lR = new Line();
lR.X1 = 0;
lR.Y1 = 0;
lR.X2 = 150;
lR.Y2 = 150;
lR.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
lR.StrokeThickness = 2;

/* declare ScaleTransformation */
ScaleTransform lRSt = new ScaleTransform();
TransformGroup lRTran = new TransformGroup();
lRTran.Children.Add(lRSt);
lR.RenderTransform = lRTran;

LineSliderR(lR);

/* Slider - Slider should be placed outside the canvas to prevent being redrawn */
Slider sliderR = new Slider();
sliderR.Minimum = 1;
sliderR.Maximum = 3;
sliderR.Value = 1;
sliderR.TickPlacement = TickPlacement.BottomRight;
sliderR.TickFrequency = 0.2;
sliderR.IsSnapToTickEnabled = true; 


public void LineSliderR(Line lRSt)
{
    Binding sliderRBind1 = new Binding();
    sliderRBind1.Source = sliderR;
    sliderRBind1.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(lRSt, ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, sliderRBind1);
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(lRSt, ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, sliderRBind1);

}
```

Why did the Binding fail if it's called to a separate method?

The two codes are (to me) identical. Both contain four same, identical, "things": 
a Line, a ScaleTransform, a Binding, and a Slider.

The first code has all 4 "things" in a function. The second code has the Binding call from a separate function. Both compiles without error: However, the Binding (between Line and Slider) works OK on the first code, but not the second. I am trying get the second code to work because I have many Line's and I don't want to repeat myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second code block, inside the method `LineSliderR`, lRSt is an object of type `Line`, while in your first block it is of type `ScaleTransform`.

If you want your second block to behave like the first, your method LineSliderR, should accept a `ScaleTransform`' as parameter:

```
public void LineSliderR(ScaleTransform lRSt)
```